# side menu navbar toggle not working in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode, jquery-mobile-navbar

I'm working on WP website from a while (I'm **beginner**) and I faced a problem in my side-menu toggle with mobile/tablet resolution.

the navbar doesn't work when I click on it [**when I add a custom "Footer" with Elements Kit plugin**].

you can [take a look](https://www.donya.com.tn/).

---

theme used [Zimed `Version: 2.0`] By Layerdrops team.

I tryed to disable the ElementsKit footer and the side-menu works, but I can't customize the main footer of the theme.
so I used to enable the custom footer that I create it by Elements kit plugin.
and I also try to change the wordpress shortcode but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion there is a conflict between the footer navigation of the plugin and the default navigation of the theme caused by using the same "id". therefore "eventListener" does not work.

have you checked that part?

Comment: yes I also think about that, but I can't edit the main footer "id" or the plugin also.
I'm not professional in WordPress. and I don't find any solution for that only if I disable the plugin footer